# Xamarin.Android. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Clicking on button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I press any button I get:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
namespace Xamarin.Android.Pluralsight
{
    [Activity(Label = "Xamarin.Android.Pluralsight", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Button _buttonPrevious;
        private Button _buttonNext;
        private ImageView _imageProfile;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _buttonPrevious = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonPrevious);
        _buttonNext = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonNext);
        _imageProfile = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageProfile);

        _buttonNext.Click += buttonNext_Click;
        _buttonPrevious.Click += buttonPrevious_Click;
    }

    private void buttonPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _imageProfile.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.image1);
    }

    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _imageProfile.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.image2);
    }
}
```

}

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Previous"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Next"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Why? What's wrong with this code? This code is rudimentary, but I cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

At runtime, Android can't find your imageProfile view, so`FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageProfile)` is returning null.

Try deleting the contents (not the file) of `Resource.designer.cs` and rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It was very helpful. It works for me.